# MySQL Indexes and possible_keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, key

I ran an EXPLAIN statement on one of my common queries I run, and I am curious why my "possible_keys" only match 2/3 of my indexed fields. Is this because im using a LIKE clause?

Here is a link to the image of my MySQL Console showing my explained query and indexes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3iZI.png

If you notice only 2 of my indexes are appearing in the possible_keys column.

Additionally, why is my 'key' column showing NULL?
Id very much like to understand this better, and if there is a good resource out there where I can read up on this in more detail I would greatly appreciate a link and some input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Possible_keys` only considers indexes that *might* be relevant to the current query.  You may certainly have other indexes in the table, even if they can't be of any help to this query.

MySQL considers the frequency of values in a column, and may decide not to use an index because you're searching for values that don't help to narrow down the set of rows.

By analogy, if you look at the index at the back of a book, you don't see the word "the" in the index.  It would just list of every page number in the book, which would be pointless.  There's no reason to use the index in that case, and it would actually make the search *slower* to use the index.

Likewise, you're searching for terms `empl_id=86560 AND week_number=22`, but these specific values may be so common in your table that MySQL decides it's more economical just to read every row and discard the ones that *don't* match

The term `deduction_code LIKE '%VIS%'` cannot use an index.  By analogy, search the phone book and find me every name with "VIS" in the *middle* of someone's name.  The fact that the book is sorted doesn't help, you still have to search it cover-to-cover.

Your `key` column is NULL because the query decided to use no index for this query.  The other clue for this is that the `type` column says "ALL" which means it is doing a table-scan, reading every row in the table.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types

You might be interested in my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really).

Comment: That all makes sense, but wouldnt it be far more efficient to use the indexes? The table has 300k rows of data. Is there a way to force MySQL to use a particular index? or multiple indexes even?

Comment: It's not always more efficient to use an index.  See my edited answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info! I will definitely take a look at your presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using like with a % at the beginning. So it cannot use the index and it has to do a full scan for that column. So it will not use the index for deduction code.

But for the actual selected index, MySQL query optimizer does some heuristic guesses. And it may choose to ignore existing keys if it decides a full table scan would be faster than using those indexes. You may force mysql to use indexes if you want. You can check the mysql documentation for the details.

Comment: Ahh I had a feeling that was the case! Thanks very much for confirming !